# Reordering Cells with UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource and NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, nsfetchedresultscontroller, ios13

I'm using a [UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdiffabledatasource) and a `NSFetchedResultsController` to populate my `UICollectionView` inside my `UIViewController`.

To add the ability of reordering cells I added a `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` and subclassed `UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource` in order to use it's `canMoveItemAt:` and `moveItemAt:` methods.

When reordering a cell the following things happen:

1. `moveItemAt:` is called and I update the objects position property and save the MOC
2. `controllerDidChangeContent:` of the `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` is called and I create a new snapshot from the current fetchedObjects and apply it.

When I apply `dataSource?.apply(snapshot, animatingDifferences: true)` the cells switch positions back immediately. If I set `animatingDifferences: false` it works, but all cells are reloaded **visibly**.

Is there any best practice here, how to implement cell reordering on a `UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource` and a `NSFetchedResultsController`?

Here are my mentioned methods:

```swift
// ViewController 
func createSnapshot(animated: Bool = true) {
    var snapshot = NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot<Int, Favorite>()
    snapshot.appendSections([0])
    snapshot.appendItems(provider.fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects ?? [])
    dataSource?.apply(snapshot, animatingDifferences: animated)
}

// NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate
func controllerDidChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
    createSnapshot(animated: false)
}

// Subclassed UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, moveItemAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {
    provider.moveFavorite(from: sourceIndexPath.row, to: destinationIndexPath.row)
}

// Actual cell moving in a provider class
public func moveFavorite(from source: Int, to destination: Int) {
    guard let favorites = fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects else { return }
    if source < destination {
        let partialObjects = favorites.filter({ $0.position <= destination && $0.position >= source })

        for object in partialObjects {
            object.position -= 1
        }

        let movedFavorite = partialObjects.first
        movedFavorite?.position = Int64(destination)
    }
    else {
        let partialObjects = favorites.filter({ $0.position >= destination && $0.position <= source })

        for object in partialObjects {
            object.position += 1
        }

        let movedFavorite = partialObjects.last
        movedFavorite?.position = Int64(destination)
    }
    do {
        try coreDataHandler.mainContext.save()
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

Comment: did you ever find a fix for this?

Answer (score 2):

No need to subclass. Starting in iOS 14.0, UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource supports [reordering handlers](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdiffabledatasource/3600965-reorderinghandlers) you can implement.

```
let data_source = UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource<MySection, MyModelObject>( collectionView: collection_view, cellProvider:
{
    [weak self] (collection_view, index_path, video) -> UICollectionViewCell? in
        
    let cell = collection_view.dequeueReusableCell( withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: index_path ) as! MyCollectionViewCell

    if let self = self
    {
        //setModel() is my own method to update the view in MyCollectionViewCell
        cell.setModel( self.my_model_objects[index_path.item] )
    }

    return cell
})

// Allow every item to be reordered as long as there's 2 or more
diffable_data_source.reorderingHandlers.canReorderItem = 
{ 
    item in 
    my_model_objects.count >= 2 return true 
}

//Update your model objects before the reorder occurs. 
//You can also use didReorder, but it might be useful to have your
//model objects in the correct order before dequeueReusableCell() is 
//called so you can update the cell's view with the correct model object.
diffable_data_source.reorderingHandlers.willReorder = 
{ 
    [weak self] transaction in
    
    guard let self = self else { return }
    
    self.my_model_objects = transaction.finalSnapshot.itemIdentifiers
}
```

Comment: Based on the sample code for this, reordering handlers only seem to work with list layouts when the list cells have a reorder accessory showing? How do I get this to work with a custom compositional layout?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69844189/how-can-i-use-uicollectionviewdiffabledatasource-reorderhandlers-with-a-custom-c

Answer (score 1):

My solution to the same issue is to subclass the UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource and implement the canMoveItemAt method in the subclass to answer true.
The animation seems to work fine for me if the longPressAction case of .ended does three things:

1. update the model
2. call dateSource.collectionView(..moveItemAt:..)
3. run your dataSource.apply

The other usual methods for drag behavior have to be also implemented which it looks like you have done. FYI for others- These methods are well documented in the section for 'Reordering Items Interactively' of UICollectionView. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview

```
class PGLDiffableDataSource: UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource<Int, Int> {
    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, canMoveItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

}
```