# How can I use UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource reorderHandlers with a custom compositional layout?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewdiffabledatasource

As of iOS 14, UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource has a [`reorderHandlers`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdiffabledatasource/3600513-reorderinghandlers?language=objc) property. It's demonstrated in some [sample code](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/views_and_controls/collection_views/implementing_modern_collection_views) and talked about in [WWDC 2020 session](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10045/?time=489) on Advances in Diffable Data Sources. The presenter states that you have to provide a `canReorder` and `didReorder` closure to enable the feature.

The sample code uses it in a collection view with a list layout configuration, and configures the list cells with reorder accessories. The `canReorder` and `didReorder` methods are called as expected. But if I remove the reorder accessories from the cells, reordering no longer works - it doesn't call either closure. It also doesn't work in my app, where I have a grid layout using a compositional layout.

How do I enable reordering on `UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource` without list cells and reorder accessories?

Comment: I talked to a UIKit engineer about this in a Tech Talk and it sounds like this is a bug. I filed Feedback FB9753149 in case anyone wants to dupe (or a UIKit engineer finds this post).

Answer (score 1):

I talked to another engineer in a virtual lab in WWDC 2022 about this, and it seems that the reorder accessory is just a convenience. The functionality can be achieved more manually too. Documentation is [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview) under "Reordering Items Interactively". We can use our own gesture recognizer to know when to start dragging, and call [`beginInteractiveMovement`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview/1618019-begininteractivemovementforitem) after figuring out which item to move.

`canReorderItem` must return true for this to work.

YMMV. Have fun!